# sorted in njit numba

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have `n x 3` ndarray and wanted to sort it by 3-rd column.In 3-rd column there MAY BE some `np.inf`. Anyway, I used `sorted` function. After that I used `njit` decorator on my main function but got different result... So I wrote that code to check what's going on:

```
#Sorting Functions
import numpy as np
from numba import njit
@njit
def sort_me_numba(arr):
    res = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
    return res

def sort_me_python(arr):
    res = sorted(arr, key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
    return res

#Making data format I have
arr = np.concatenate([np.random.normal(loc=0.1, scale=0.005, size=1_000).reshape((-1, 1)) for i in range(3)], axis=1)
samples = [0, 14, 53, 344, 43, 654, 435, 33]
arr[samples, 2] = np.inf

print('-----------NUMBA with numpy array------------')
sort_me_numba(arr)

print('-----------PYTHON with numpy array------------')
sort_me_python(arr)

print('-----------PYTHON with list------------')
sort_me_python(list(arr))
```

And there is really some differences. But when `samples = [0, 1, 2, 442]` - there is no differences. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function tell to Numba/CPython to sort lines based on the second item which contains Inf values. Two infinity values are considered equal so a sorting algorithm can change the order of the lines having Inf values in the second item of the target lines. The different results is due to different algorithms being used. This is expected because the **sorting algorithm is not guaranteed to be stable** (ie. preserve the order of *equal lines*).

To solve the problem, you need to use a stable algorithm. **`np.argsort`** can be used to find the ordering of the value and the parameter `kind` can be tuned so to choose a stable algorithm (called `"stable"`). Additionally, `np.argsort` should also be faster than `sorted` on Numpy arrays because it does not cause many lambda calls nor compute Numpy lines as slow CPython objects. This should do the job:

```py
arr[np.argsort(-arr[:,2], kind='stable')]
```

---

**Update:** @creanion is right about `sorted` being mandatory stable so Numba should fulfil the same constraints specified in the Python documentation. However, the documentation of Numba specify that the `key` argument is not yet supported. That being said, this argument clearly impact the result/behaviour of the `sorted` function. Thus, it looks like it has been at least partially implemented recently.

Whether this is a **bug in Numba** is disputable since the key item is supposed not to be supported. Indeed, without this parameter the stability is not a problem (two items can either be truly equal or said to be different though they may be equal -- eg. for NaN). Note such stability constraints has a strong implication on the Numba code since it prevent some algorithms to be used like the famous Quick-Sort for example.

Comment: Well, but with numba it's not working) Not implemented I guess

Comment: Yes, it is unfortunately unsupported yet in Numba (version 0.55.1). AFAIK there is no efficient simple way to do that in Numba. The best solution is to implement a custom radix sort (which should be stable and fast). This has the default to be a bit tedious/complex to implement bug certainly fast.

Comment: python doc fact: `The built-in sorted() function is guaranteed to be stable.`  But numba breaks that, then?

Comment: @creanion Indeed. I was not aware of that. Thank you for pointing that out. I updated the answer to give a bit more information about that.