# NameError: global name '<lambda>' is not defined when using the sorted() function

Tags: python, lambda, conda, nameerror

In the application I am creating I have this list:

```
scores = [[232178, 0], [167883, 1], [174491, 2], [890, 3], [190860, 4], [137581, 5], [2126, 6], [200983, 7]]
```

Then I want to sort them based on their first element of each element of that list and access that index.

```
sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[0])[0][1]
```

However when I run it, it gives an error:

```
NameError: global name '<lambda>' is not defined
```

I am using a conda environment with python 3.7.4

Any help would be appreciated!

Code used:
Given a video of messed up frames, use each frame to find the next closest frame to build the original video

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, cuda
import copy

@jit(target_backend='cuda')
def foo():
    images = []

    for i in range(1,10):#3941):
        print(f'i:{i}')
        filename = "extracted/" + str(i).zfill(4) + '.png'
        image = cv2.imread(filename)
        height, width, layers = image.shape
        images.append(image)
    print('loaded images')
    return images, width, height

@jit(target_backend='cuda')
def bar(images_list, iwidth, iheight, where):
    images_new = [images_list.pop(3)]#3157)]
    c = 0
    while len(images) > 1:
        scores = []
        old_image = images_new[-1]
        print(f'where:{where} c:{c}')
        for i in range(len(images_list)):
            scores.append([np.sum((images_list[i][where] - old_image[where])**2), i])
        new = sorted(scores, key=lambda x: x[0])
        images_new.append(images_list.pop(new[0][1]))
        c += 1
    print(f'where:{where} sorted images')

    video = cv2.VideoWriter(f'videoat{where}.avi', 0, 10, (iwidth, iheight))
    for image in images_new:
        video.write(image)
    print(f'where:{where} made video')
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    video.release()
    print(f'where:{where} done')

images, width, height = foo()
bar(copy.deepcopy(images),width,height,50)
```

Comment: Returns '3' as expected run in a fresh environment. Can you try restarting your kernel and running this minimal code again? Could be an issue introduced elsewhere.

Comment: Please read [mre] and make sure that someone else can **copy and paste** the code from the example **without adding or changing anything** to see the **exact problem, directly**.

Comment: alright @karl-knechtel

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72642572/sorted-in-njit-numba, which mentions questionable support for the `key` argument to `sorted` with `numba.jit`. Your error suggests that that what support it does have relies on the `key` argument having a `__name__` attribute that corresponds to a global variable, which the function generated by a lambda expression does not.

Comment: ah it never occured to me that numba.jit could break sorted, it is my first time using it as it makes calculations faster using gpu

Comment: Here we go: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#built-in-functions. This explicitly documents that `key` is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` argument to `sorted` is [not supported by Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/pysupported.html#built-in-functions).

Specifically, it looks like it might be *partially* supported (maybe it works if you pass a function defined by `def`), but your error message suggests that Numba *tries* to use the argument, but assumes its `__name__` attribute is also the name of a valid global variable. The `__name__` attribute of a function defined by a lambda expression, though, is `<lambda>`, not any global variable.

(There are probably other reasons it is not supported. Other places in the documentation mention lack of support for `**kwargs`, for example. Even though lambda expressions are commonly used for the `key` argument, it seems odd to document that it is completely unsupported if the only restriction would be to use functions defined by a `def` statement.)